# Iterating in lists of different lengths

Tags: python, mysql, list, index-error

I'm trying to add data to a MySQL table using Python from a dictionary. My dictionary is composed of keys associated with value lists of different lengths -- anywhere from a length of 1 to 150 or so. I'm using an insert statement to insert my data into the table where the keys are the field names. This is what I'd like the sql insert statement to be basically:

```
INSERT INTO table
(key1, key2, key3, ...)
VALUES
(key1value1, key2value1, key3value1, ...),
(key1value2, key2value2, key3value2, ...),
(key1value3, key2value3, key3value3, ...);
```

and so on, but I'm also okay with doing a for loop in order to have one insert statement per set of values. Here's what I have for the first elements of my lists:

```
cols = dict.keys()
vals = dict.values()
lst = [item[0] for item in vals]
sql = "INSERT INTO table (%s) VALUES (%s);" % (','.join(map(str, cols[:len(cols)])), "'{}'".format("','".join(lst)))
cursor.execute(sql)
```

And that works, effectively inserting my first set of data into one new row in my table. But the problem is when I try to increase the index in lst, for example to item[1], it says index is out of range because I have some lists with just one element. And since the lists are all different lengths I need to make this general enough so that it always works up to however many elements each list has.

If the index is out of range for some lists as it increases then I want it to skip those but keep inserting the rest. How do I do that?

Comment: Just a minor note: Use prepared statements instead of string formatting when modifying queries.

Answer (score 0):

First example will give you the `ith` element of each value in the dictionary, completely stopping when the shortest list is exhausted.

Second example will keep going, and just use a `None` value where one list is too short.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

d = {'k1':[1,2,3],
     'k2':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
     'k3':[1,8]}

for k in d.keys():
    for v in zip(*d.values()):
        print(k,v)

for k in d.keys():
    for v in zip_longest(*d.values()):
        print(k,v)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = { 'a': [1], 'b': [1, 2], 'c': [1, 2, 3] }

keys = ', '.join(data.keys())
values = ', '.join('(' + ', '.join(v) + ')' for v in (map(str, value) for value in data.values()))

print(keys)
print(values)
```

Produces:

```
a, b, c
(1), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3)
```

I'm fairly sure SQL does not allow multiple values in a single column, though.